# Can i use multi css pseudo selector classes?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Ok, is there any possible to use multi  pseudo selector classes?

I have list and i nead to add some style for two of this list elements.

Smth like:

```
li:nth-child(2+4) or li:nth-child(2,4) or li:nth-child(2|4)?
```

Answer (score 2):

Ou simplement

```
li:nth-child(2), li:nth-child(4) {}
```

Comment: You can't bypass it. It's the only possible way.

Answer (score 1):

```
li:nth-child(even); // 2,4,6,8
li:nth-child(odd); // 1,3,5,7
```

Comment: this is nice, is there any possible to use it for 2,4,7,10 - for ex?